# Does $dim(L_1)=dim(L_2)$ imply $L_1 \simeq L_2$ for $L_1,L_2$ abelian Lie algebras.

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-algebras

My question is to guess whether $L_1 \simeq L_2 \leftrightarrow dim(L_1)=dim(L_2)$ is true or false. I think that the one way is right because if there is an isomorphism, a basis is mapped to the other basis. However, I think that the other direction might be wrong, although the Lie algebras are abelian. Unfortunately, I am lacking examples of abelian lie algebras of the same dimension. Thanks for your advise!

Comment: Check whether a vector space isomorphism between $L_1$ and $L_2$ is also a Lie algebra isomorphism.

Comment: @DanielFischer So if $\phi$ is a vector space isomorphism, I get $\phi([x,y])=\phi(xy-yx)=\phi(xy)-\phi(yx)$ which only equals $[\phi(x),\phi(y)]=\phi(x)\phi(y)-\phi(y)\phi(x)$, if $\phi$ is multiplicative(?), which is not given in general? Can I then conclude that having the same dimension does not mean they are isomorphic?

Comment: The multiplication on a Lie algebra is the Lie bracket, $[\,\cdot\,,\,\cdot\,]$; $xy$ isn't defined. Now, for an abelian Lie algebra, what is $[x,y]$?

Comment: A map $\phi$ of Lie algebras is just a map of the underlying vector spaces with $\phi([x, y]) = [\phi(x), \phi(y)]$.

Comment: @DanielFischer my bad. Since $L_1$ is abelian $[x,y]=0$ for all $x,y \in L_1$, So $\phi([x,y])=\phi(0)=0$. Furthermore, $[\phi(x),\phi(y)]=0$ because $\phi:L_1\rightarrow L_2$ and $[v,w]=0$ for all $v,w \in L_2$, too.

Comment: Right, and so every linear map between abelian Lie algebras is a Lie algebra homomorphism. (This is of course very much not the case for non-abelian Lie algebras.)

Comment: @DanielFischer Does that mean, that for every dimension there is (up to isomorphism) only at most $1$ abelian lie algebra? Thanks for your help and have a nice day :).

Comment: Yes. An abelian Lie algebra is effectively just a vector space (on every vector space, you can - if you want to - consider the trivial Lie bracket; that adds no information).